# Is a diet high in fruit as detrimental as one that includes sugary snacks?

Tags: diet, food, fruit

I'm currently trying to eat a lot healthier, and to that end I've cut out any sugary snacks - cakes, cookies, chocolate bars, protein bars and so on. I've noticed that I've mostly ended up replacing them with nuts, and a lot of fruit.

I'll get through a large container of pineapple, a couple of bananas, a large fresh orange juice and various other fruits through the day. I'm trying to make sure all my fruit is raw and fresh but, even so, are the sugars from fruits likely to be as detrimental to my dieting (the aim is weight loss & muscle gain), as if I simply cheated and had the odd sugary snack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly identified the bad foods, so that's a good start. You haven't mentioned drinks; if you consume sugary drinks (even from fresh fruit) you better stop.

The problem is that you replaced all of these with fruit and nuts. Fruit is quite overhyped. It is completely true that it is healthy. But you don't need that much nutrients. It's not like if you don't eat few pounds of a 'super-food' you will be malnutritioned.

What is true though, is that modern fruits have lots of fructose. And that is basically sugar.

Try to replace a lot of the fruits you currently eat with vegetables.

Don't strive to eat everything raw or in whatever form a hipsterish blog would suggest. Eat it in a way that you like it, so you have a good chance of keeping following the diet.

Comment: by the same token, if you prefer fruits to vegetables, eat them instead

Comment: @RobinAshe fruit is a lot more nutritionally dense than vegetables. Personal preferences aside, vegetables are much better for fat loss.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've noticed that I don't eat many vegetables at all compared to fruit right now, I'll work on that.

Answer (score -2):

No, not the same. Fruit, in addition to the sugar, also contains fiber.  The fiber will slow digestion and keep the sugar in fruits from quickly going right to your blood stream (and thus spiking insulin).

Comment: The effect is not as pronounced as you might wish it were.

Comment: @MikeS care to back that statement up?

Comment: @MikeS how might I wish it were? I was simply stating that there is a difference, I did not say or allege at how much - which answers the OP question.

Comment: To much fruit will still make you fat - which is the reason why the OP asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @MikeS that might be why, but it was not his question (Will eating fruit make me fat?).  I'm still not sure how my response does not answer his question.

Comment: why you trying to split hairs? YES eating the quantities of fruit the OP described in his question's content WILL make him fat and there is NOT much difference between sugary snacks and a glass of orange juice. A glass of orange juice has about 80-90% of the calories (mostly from sugar) of a can of coke.

Comment: @MikeS a glass of orange juice is not "a fruit". I agree that there is not much difference between sugary snacks and a glass of orange juice.

Comment: @MikeS and I'm pretty confident that if the OP is only eating "a large container of pineapple, a couple of bananas, a large fresh orange juice and various other fruits through the day" the OP will NOT get fat as that is probably less calories taken in than burned off.

Comment: if thats ALL the OP is eating, then they need to be stepping up their calories ;).

Comment: For all the down voters here, you might want to check out thefruitarian.com. Michael Arnstein eats only produce and is a very fast and very fit athlete. I guarantee he would not have the same results if a sugary-snack-arian.